# How to prove that $Nil_*M_n(R) = M_n(Nil_*R)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

How to prove that $Nil_*M_n(R) = M_n(Nil_*R)$?,

$Nil_*R$ is the Baer's lower nilradical (It is the smallest semiprime ideal in R, and is equal to the intersection of all the prime ideals in R)

$M_n(R)$ is the ring of matrices over R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows immediately from ideal correspondence. That is, the ideals of $M_n(R)$ are exactly of the form $M_n(I)$ where $I\lhd R$.

It is not hard to see that prime ideals correspond and intersections correspond in the obvious way.